# Facebook events page integration

Tags: facebook, events, integration

Can I integrate facebook events pages into my website? If so, what would it look like?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Questions here must be programming related. Please read the [FAQ](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn what types of questions are allowed here.

Comment: Here is a great article detailing how to do it very easily: http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/07/display-facebook-events-to-your-website.html

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no social plugin for events, unlike comments, "like" etc

You'll have to use the Facebook Graph API at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/. It returns JSON, which you need to create HTML elements to display them.

So it'll look however you want it to look.